# Xamarin.Forms macOS splash screen

Tags: macos, xamarin.forms, splash-screen

How to create a splash screen for Mac project?
I found information only for iOS, Android, UWP projects about splash screen and nothing about MacOS project.

Comment: If you want to add MACOS project.You Have to work it on VS for mac . Then, add a project into the solution by right-clicking the solution and selecting Add > Add New Existing Project.You can then select Mac > App > Cocoa App and name it whatever you want, but ideally, the name has a suffix of .macOs.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFTI have already a solution with Mac, UWP, Android, and iOS on my mac and windows machines. problem is that I can't find any information on how to make a splash screen for my Mac project in xamarin.forms.